# Mule: Using higher version of spring and hibernate than bundled in mule server bundle library

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am using Mule 3.5.2 and in mule studio creating a mule project includes a Mule Server 3.5.2 EE library already having spring and hibernate specific versions  (spring --->3.2.10, hibernate -->3.6.0).

Is it possible to use higher versions of spring and hibernate than already bundled in mule server library?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is possible to override the spring with newer version, but I managed to use a newer version of DBUtils in one of my applications (instead of the old version bundled in mule).

Try to exclude all spring dependencies in mule jars, in the pom. In a fresh 3.5.2 project would be something like:

```
<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloveretl</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloveretl-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And insert the dependency of the spring version that you want to use. Insert the following entry into the **mule-deploy.properties** to force the classloader to search the classes from the application first:

```
loader.override=org.springframework
```

This was not tested. Hope this can help you.